# What version of vCenter is included in Essentials Plus Kit?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Sorry for asking sales-oriented questions, but vmware forums are closed for maintenance (or newcomers?)

We're thinking about getting http://www.vmware.com/vmwarestore/smb-solutions-server.html , VMware vSphere 4.1 Essentials Plus Kit for 3 hosts, but I do not know what version of vCenter is included, so that we could download and test the product. Orchestrator? Lab Manager? No product is called vCenter server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too find their site a pain in the *ss to navigate, but after a few hours spent I found what I am looking for.
Go to downloads, then Vmware Vsphere, and there you see ESXi and VCenter. (or click [this](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vsphere_4/4_0) link).

I have two essentials plus and I am extremely satisfied with it :-).

Comment: Hm but those links are not for trial downloads, I'm not authorized to download anything .. maybe it's because the maintenance ..